# NSubstitute ForPartsOf calling concrete implementation event when substituted

Tags: c#, unit-testing, subclass, nsubstitute

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public string MyFunc(string name)
    {            
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new Exception("Blank Name");
        }

        return name;
    }

    public double MyFuncWrapper(string name)
    {
        var value = MyFunc(name);

        return value;
    }
```

In trying to test it, I was under the impression that NSubstitute's `ForPartsOf` effectively subclassed my class and replaced the flagged methods; so I did this:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMyFuncWrapper()
{
    // Arrange
    var myClass = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>();            
    myClass.MyFunc(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns("Test");

    // Act
    var result = myClass.MyFuncWrapper("");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal("Test", result);
}
```

However, I get the exception raised from, what I understood to be, my substituted method.  Oddly, it appears that the following line:

```
myClass.MyFunc(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns("Test");
```

Is actually calling the concrete function immediately.  Looking [here](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/), it appeared that a construct like this may solve the problem (although it does use the phrase "playing it safe" which sounds quite vague):

```
myClass.When(a => a.MyFunc(Arg.Any<string>())).DoNotCallBase();
```

However, calling this actually invokes MyFunc immediately in the same way.  Clearly I'd misunderstood the `ForPartsOf` method; my question is: can I do what I'm attempting using NSubstitute, or do I need to resort to manually subclassing MyClass?

Comment: What happens if you add `virtual` to the function declarations?

Comment: ... and suddenly it all clicks into place - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design for `NSubstitute` (and for most mocking frameworks).

[The docs](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/) state:

> For starters, NSubstitute can only work with virtual members of the
>   class, so any non-virtual code in the class will actually execute!

Thus, you need to add `virtual` to the function declarations you plan to mock. 
*Or (as per the docs):*

> If possible, stick to substituting interfaces.